# How to Pass a Value From a Window to a UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I want to pass a value from MainWindow into my UserControl! I passed a value to my UserControl and the UserControl showed me the value in a MessageBox, but it is not showing the value in a TextBox. Here is my code:

**MainWindow(Passing Value To UserControl)**

```
try
{
    GroupsItems abc = null;
    if (abc == null)
    {
        abc = new GroupsItems();
        abc.MyParent = this;
        abc.passedv(e.ToString(), this);

    }
}
catch (Exception ee)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
}
```

**UserControl**

```
public partial class GroupsItems : UserControl
{
    public MainWindow MyParent { get; set; }
    string idd = "";
    public GroupsItems()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        data();
    }

    public void passedv(string id, MainWindow mp)
    {
        idd = id.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(idd);
        data();
    }

    public void data()
    {
        if (idd!="")
        {
            MessageBox.Show(idd);
            texbox.Text = idd;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT(using BINDING and INotifyProperty )**

.....

```
   public GroupsItems()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

    public void passedv()
    {
        textbox1.Text = Text;
    }

}

public class Groupitm : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _text = "";

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _text)
            {
                _text = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dude... you're trying to use WPF as if it were WinForms. It just doesn't work like that. Please learn how to use data `Binding` and the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) before you write any more WPF.

Comment: @Sheridan I do not think he has to use `Binding`, MVVM etc if he does not want to. I agree with you that it is the ultimate experience but it is still possible to use older patterns as well.

Comment: @Sheridan my code using binding is also not working:(

Comment: @meilke, I completely accept that anything is possible. Please note that I didn't mention MVVM or the ultimate experience. It's just that the question author will find WPF easier to write if he writes it the WPF way and not the WinForms way that he is currently using.

Comment: @Sheridan please take a moment to view my updated code

Comment: @user2835256, if you show us your `Binding` code, we can help with that also.

Comment: Oooh, that was quick. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39740/discussion-between-user2835256-and-sheridan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem here is with reference.

When you create new object in code behind, new object will be created and this is not the same object which you have in xaml code. So you should use following code:

```
<local:GroupsItems x:Name="myGroupsItems"/>
```

and in code behind you don't have to create new object. You should use object that you added in XAML:

```
...
myGroupsItems.MyParent = this;
myGroupsItems.passedv(e.ToString(), this);
...
```

[Here](http://sdrv.ms/1hizQ4g) is example solution (sampleproject).

Comment: Thank's kmatyaszek! Stay Blessed :)

Comment: Name doesn't allow numbers, so I used `<local:GroupsItems x:Uid="1"/>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `data` in the constructor when `idd` is still `""` which results in the text box still being empty. Changing the `MyParent` property does not change that. Only `passedv` does. But at that point you do not have the parent set. Just call `data` in `passedv`, too.

Comment: did you get the Second message from `MessageBox.Show(idd)` data

Comment: @Bharath yes i got that message

Comment: Hm...if you get the second message, textbox MUST be filled by idd text. Try to clear and rebuild your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public partial class GroupsItems : UserControl
{
   //properties and methods

    private string idd="";

    public string IDD
    {
    get{return idd;}
    set{
        idd=value; 
        textBox1.Text=idd;
        }
    }

   //other properties and methods
}
```

Usage:

In your Main form:

```
    abc = new GroupsItems();
    abc.IDD="sometext";
    MainGrid1.Children.Add(abc);   //Grid or any other container for your UserControl
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Binding` example, your `GroupItem` class looks ok, except that you need to pass in the name of the changed property:

```
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _text)
            {
                _text = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, in `GroupsItems`, you shouldn't be accessing the `TextBox`. In WPF, we manipulate the data, not the UI... but as we use `Binding` objects to data bind the data to the UI controls, they automatically update (*if we correctly implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface*).

So first, let's add a data property into your code behind (which should also implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface) like you did in your `GroupItem` class:

```
private GroupItem _item = new GroupItem();

public GroupItem Item
{
    get { return _item; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _item)
        {
            _item = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's try using a `Binding` on a `TextBox.Text` property:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Item.Text}" />
```

See how we bind the `Text` property of your `GroupItem` class to the `TextBox.Text` property... now all we need to do is to change the value of the `Item.Text` property and watch it update in the UI:

```
<Button Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click" />

...

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Item.Text = "Can you see me now?";
}
```

Alternatively, you could put this code into your `passedv` method if you are calling that elsewhere in your project. Let me know how you get on.

---

UPDATE >>>

In your `GroupItem` class, try changing the initialization to this:

```
private string _text = "Any text value";
```

Can you now see that text in the UI when you run the application? If not, then try adding/copying the whole `Text` property into your code behind and changing the `TextBox` declaration to this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
```

If you can't see the text value now, you've really got problems... you *have* implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your code behind haven't you?