# How to assign property (get; set;) to a WPF User Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to learn property (get and set) in C#. I'm still new to the language and currently making a simple program using WPF with some textboxes, as you can see in the pictures.

So, here are the description :

- Input : it's where user can type the input, located at MainWindow
- Output 1 : it's where to see the typed string in input, located at MainWindow
- Output 2 : same like Output 1, located inside tab one, at MainWindow.
- Output 3 : same like Output 1, located inside tab two, still at MainWindow.
- Output 4 : same like Output 1, located inside tab two, referred to local UserControl Page1.
- Button : a button to "save" the input

Here are the codes : 
Main Window : solution --> I added `x:Name="Page1"` after `local:page1`

```
<!-- MainWindow.xaml -->
<Window x:Class="TestGetSet.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestGetSet"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="212" Margin="37,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="447">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <TextBox x:Name="output2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="156,76,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <Label x:Name="label2" Content="Output 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>

        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <TextBox x:Name="output3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="321,26,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <local:Page1 x:Name="Page1"/>
                <Label x:Name="label3" Content="Output 3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="321,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

    <TextBox x:Name="input" Text=""/>
    <TextBox x:Name="output1" Text=""/>        
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Click="button_Click"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Input" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="37,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Output 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="364,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

MainWindow code behind : solution --> added one line `Page1.passingvalue(..)`

```
// MainWindow.xaml.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public myProperty myProp = new myProperty();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {     
        myProp.myData = input.Text;
        output1.Text = myProp.myData;
        output2.Text = myProp.myData;
        output3.Text = myProp.myData;

        Page1.passingvalue(myProp.myData);
    }
}
```

Next is Page1.xaml (No changes made here for the solution)

```
<!-- Page1.xaml-->
<UserControl x:Class="TestGetSet.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestGetSet"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="output4" Text=""/>
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Output 4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="92,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Page1 code behind : solution--> deleted timer and added `passingvalue`

```
// Page1.xaml.cs    
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel; 

namespace TestGetSet
{
    public partial class Page1 : UserControl
    {
        private Thread _receiveThread;
        myProperty myProp = new myProperty();

        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            /*DispatcherTimer MyTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
            MyTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);  
            MyTimer.Tick += MyTimer_Tick;
            MyTimer.Start();*/
        }

        public void passingvalue(string m)
        {
            output4.Text = m;
        }

        /*private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            output4.Text = myProp.myData;
        }*/
    }
}
```

Last one, the property, simple version :

```
// myProperty.cs

namespace TestGetSet
{
    public class myProperty
    {
        public string myData { get; set }           
    }
}
```

Property with INotifyPropertyChanged :

```
// myProperty.cs
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace TestGetSet
{
    public class myProperty : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _textdata;

        public string myData {
            get
            {
                return _textdata;
            }
            set
            {
                _textdata = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("myData");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the screenshots of the program window :
[one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAP2i.png)
and
[two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bjsC.png)

As you can see, only Output4 is empty and the other outputs still give me results even though I don't use INotifyPropertyChanged. My question is why, and how can I fix this? I wonder if it's because I'm using UserControl for Page1, which the Output4 is in. I've been looking for the answer but came up with nothing. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Okay so I updated the code. It's working now. I got the reference for `passingvalue` from : [How to Pass a Value From a Window to a UserControl in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514617/how-to-pass-a-value-from-a-window-to-a-usercontrol-in-wpf)

Thank you.

Comment: Provide entire XAML so that it looks exactly like your image. No one will bother to add missing pieces in your code.

Comment: The property 'myprop' defined inside the code-behind of page1 is a new instance of class 'myProperty' and so it is empty. The properties of type myProperty defined in MainWindow and in Page1 are two properties with same name but are different instances of the same class. If you want to "share" the property between mainwindow and page1 you should consider the use of Data Binding https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: @NareshRavlani whole code has been added. Sorry.

Comment: Since you are not using bindings you do not have to use INotifyPropertyChanged. Try setting some value in the getter like this public string myData { get {return "Bla";} set } . Now you get Bla

Comment: @MatijaK. When I tried using `private string _textdata="bambi" ` and `public string myData{get{return _textdata;} set{_textdata value;}}` ... output4 displayed bambi well. I don't know why.

Comment: Classes and properties (and methods, constants, and enums) in C# are UpperCamelCase. Pretty much only variables and fields are lowerCamelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here is that you misstakes the MainWindow's myProperty and Page1's myProperty.

In Page1, you set the output4.Text using `myProp.myData` which is wrong because myProp is the Page1's myProp which is never updated.

If you pass the MainWindow's reference to Page1 and instead write something like `output4.Text = myMainWindowReferenc.myProp.myData;` it will work as intended.

You could also add setting to output4 in your button_Click function by naming the Page1 in the XAML:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myProp.myData = input.Text;
    output1.Text = myProp.myData;
    output2.Text = myProp.myData;
    output3.Text = myProp.myData;
    Page1.output4.Text = myProp.myData;
}
```

Comment: I understand now. So I just need to put `x:Name="Page1" ` next to `local:Page1` in MainWindow.xaml. Thank you very much. I'll update my post with the solution.